# How can I put a name's prefix in front in citations but *not* in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, sorting

For my Dutch thesis I need to have the prefix to a name when using the `\cite` command but not in the bibliography. So basically what I need is

> Cite: ‘De Jonge’
>
> Bibliography: ‘Jonge, Marinus, de’

I cannot achieve this at the same time with `biblatex`, as it seems that I need `useprefix=true` for the citations and `useprefix=false` for the bibliography.

Can anyone help?

Comment: More detailed question dealing with "(Labov 1972; de Saussure 1995)" instead of "(de Saussure 1995; Labov 1972)" asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30276/9075.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

domwass' solution has one problem: In the bibliography, author names will be typeset without the prefix at the start, but *sorting* will still use the name prefix. So I suggest to a) set `useprefix=false` when loading `biblatex` b) use domwass' hack to set the underlying toggle to `true` at the begin of the document c) use the hack again to set it to `false` at the begin of the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[useprefix=false,style=authoryear]{biblatex}% "useprefix=false" is the default

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {de Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch. This helps me with a related problem - I like to use the prefix in both citations and the bibliography, but sort without it. I can adapt your solution with `\AtEveryBibitem{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}`.

Comment: I also add `\AtEveryCite{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}` because I have citation commands in the `note` of the bibliography. So, I need this to have the prefix printed in these citations that appear in the bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the option `useprefix=true` and put the following in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginBibliography{\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother
```

I did not test it, though, since you did not give a minimal example.