# Capitalising prefix of second name in citation with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, capitalization

The `\Cite` command in biblatex capitalises the first prefix in a list of names:

```
\cite: de Jonge and de Bruin
\Cite: De Jonge and de Bruin
```

Unfortunately in Dutch publications *all* prefices need to be capitalised. Basically I need:
De Jonge and De Bruin.

This is only valid in the text, in the bibliography I still need "Jonge, M. de and T. de Bruin" (this was achieved with the hack outlined at [How can I put a name's prefix in front in citations but *not* in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21361/how-can-i-have-the-prefix-to-a-name-in-the-citations-but-not-the-bibliography)).

Does anyone know how I can fix this in biblatex?

Comment: I'm surprised regarding your question. As far as I know the Dutch practice is *not* to capitalize the name prefix unless it is sentence initial.

Comment: Nope. If the surname has something in front of it, the prefix takes a small letter:
Mr. de Bruin
Tom de Bruin

If it has nothing in front of it, it takes a capital:
'According to De Bruin'
'As quoted in De Bruin and De Jonge.'

Comment: Well, have a look at the following link: https://books.google.de/books?id=pwbFBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA55&pg=PA55&q=%22according%20to%20van%22&f=false#v=snippet&q=%22according%20to%20van%22&f=false

Comment: What can I say, that book is wrong. And in some places horribly so, on page 70 there is a sentence beginnen with 'van Fraassen', and sentences always start with capital letters. 
Here is an English and Dutch explanation.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_(Dutch)#Collation_and_capitalisation
https://onzetaal.nl/taaladvies/advies/hoofdletters-in-namen-nynke-van-der-sluis-nynke-van-der-sluis

Comment: There are many such examples. Here is another book: https://books.google.de/books?id=9FynY2UylpoC&pg=PA301&dq=%22according+to+van%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=12zbVOKMCYWsPdO4gLAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22according%20to%20van%22&f=false

Comment: Do you really want to argue about this? I shared the rules, that's just how it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just modified the minimal example of [lockstep’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21361/how-can-i-have-the-prefix-to-a-name-in-the-citations-but-not-the-bibliography#21383) to your previous question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[useprefix=false,style=authoryear]{biblatex}% "useprefix=false" is the default

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {de Author, A. and de Bruin, T.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \toggletrue{blx@useprefix}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\MakeCapital{#1}}}% this is the relevant line of code
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \togglefalse{blx@useprefix}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{#1}}% this sets the name prefix back
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

Some text \Autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the error: "Argument of \MakeCapital has an extra }".

Both with the minimal example above and my original document.

(and if I ignore the errors it works :D )

Comment: @Tom, strange, I don’t get an error. Which version are you using? I have biblatex.sty 2011/05/12 v1.4c

Comment: v0.9a :D. Updating now.

Comment: Ok, so after ages trying to update tex, it now works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there are better ways to do this:

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd\NLCite{\begingroup
  \toggletrue{blx@useprefix}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\MakeCapital{##1}}%
  \@ifnextchar[\@NLCiteo\@NLCite}
\def\@NLCite#1{\cite{#1}\endgroup}
\def\@NLCiteo[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\@NLCiteoo{#1}}{\@NLCiteox{#1}}}
\def\@NLCiteox#1#2{\cite[#1]{#2}\endgroup}
\def\@NLCiteoo#1[#2]#3{\cite[#1][#2]{#3}\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Now `\NLCite` has the same syntax as `\Cite`, but does what you want.