# van prefix is not in capital at beginning of sentence

Tags: biblatex, citing, capitalization

The [answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226893/biblatex-handling-of-dutch-van-prefix) states that "van" prefix should be in capitals when it appears at the beginning of a sentence. But the code below typesets "van Dijk". How can I get "Van Dijk" when it appears at the beginning of a sentence?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}            
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,useprefix=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dijk,
  author       = {van Dijk, A.},
  title        = {Some Nice Title},
  date         = 2015,
  publisher    = {P. Ublisher},
  location     = {Place},
}
\end{filecontents*}   
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}  

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  
\textcite{dijk} not capitalising start of sentence
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer to the linked question does not seem to say what you claim. The rule for Dutch prefixes is that the first one is capitalized when the first name or first initial is does not precede it, except when it is a shortened version (with an apostrophe). See for example [this article](http://www.dutchgenealogy.nl/how-to-capitalize-dutch-names-with-prefixes/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\textcite` command uses the standard capitalization; however the `biblatex` package provides `\Textcite` for use at the beginning of a sentence (section 3.7.2 of the manual).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}            
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,useprefix=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dijk,
  author       = {van Dijk, A.},
  title        = {Some Nice Title},
  date         = 2015,
  publisher    = {P. Ublisher},
  location     = {Place},
}
\end{filecontents*}   
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}  

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  
\Textcite{dijk} capitalising start of sentence
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

[image]