# name prefix lowercase in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

**Short version**: How do I prevent biblatex from capitalizing the first word of every bibliography entry?

**Long version**: I have an author called (nearly) "Paolo di Italia" and biblatex (called with `useprefix` option) renders the name prefix very well, but in my bibliography of authoryear style, the prefix happens to stand at the beginning of the entry and therefore is capitalized. How do I prevent this, but of course still capitalize normal last names?

**In other words**: In my understanding, a bibliography entry is not a sentence. Biblatex evaluates this differently, forcing capitalization and a closing dot. The dot can easily removed with `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}`, but what about the capitalization of the first word?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,useprefix]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@book{regular,author = {Paolo di Italia},date = {2005}}
@book{other,author = {Some Otherguy},date = {2005}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{regular}\\\cite{other}\\\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

I want the references entry to be "**d**i Italia, …", but still "**O**therguy, …" - just exactly like in the citation output above.

**"{di Italia}" isn't an option**: I can **not** just mark it with brackets like "Paolo {di} Italia" or "Paolo {di Italia}". The first would make the citation be just "Italia" , the second can't be used because the author's name is repeated later in the bibliography entry with the last name abbreviated – which then would be rendered as "Paolo d." instead of "Paolo di I.".

Comment: Redefine begentry to \midsentence. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226893/biblatex-handling-of-dutch-van-prefix/228215#228215.

Comment: It is better to write `author = {di Italia, Paolo}`; and you can use braces if you combine it with `sortname = {<whatever>}`. But linked-to answer in the earlier comment is a more general solution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I *knew* it would be that simple – thank you very much, this does exactly what I want. In my bbx file, I changed `\newbibmacro*{begentry}{}` to `\newbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}`.