# Sorting biblatex names with space

Tags: biblatex

I want "De Groote" to be sorted before "Deane" but somehow `biblatex` eats spaces within names as far as sorting is concerned. Can this be influenced by some switch somewhere?

This is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}



@book{Deane92a,
        author = {Paul D. Deane},
        booktitle = {Grammar in Mind and Brain: {Explorations in Cognitive Syntax}},
        number = {2},
        publisher = {Mouton de Gruyter},
        series = {Cognitive Linguistics Research},
        sortname = {Paul Deane},
        title = {Grammar in Mind and Brain: {Explorations in Cognitive Syntax}},
        year = {1992}}


@proceedings{FG2008,
        address = {Stanford, CA},
        booktitle = {Proceedings of {FG 2008: The 13th Conference on Formal Grammar}},
        editor = {de Groote, Philippe},
        publisher = {CSLI Publications},
        title = {Proceedings of {FG 2008: The 13th conference on Formal Grammar}},
        year = {2008}}



\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
        natbib=true,
%   style=langsci-unified,
        citestyle=langsci-unified,
        backend=biber,
]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding this to your `.bib` entry: `sortkey = {De, Philippe}` Your entry will then be alphabetically treated as `De` instead of `De Groote`, which should be what you want.

Comment: Although depending on the style you are going for, sorting it as `Groote` may be more correct, so you should check with the entity you are creating the document for on how to treat surname prefixes.

Comment: Thanks. And there is no way to do this via a switch? Since next time I may do not want these sortkeys. And I would have to add sortkeys to a lot of items and may miss some.

Comment: There possibly is, but judging from the wide range of questions that exist on this topic there are quite a number of issues with names using prefixes (because everyone wants them to behave in a different way). You may want to check this question and the ones linked to it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226893/118712

Comment: Thanks! As for suggestion one: What if I have several names with "De "? They should be sorted with respect to each other. sortname="De~Grote, Philippe" seems to be the solution.