# 'vom' prefix is not showing up in text citation

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,DIV=8,BCOR=1cm,openright,parskip=never]{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        natbib=true,
        style=authoryear,
        maxbibnames=99,
        maxcitenames=1,
        url=false,
        isbn=false,
        doi=false,
        useprefix=false,
        backref=true,
        hyperref=true,
        firstinits=false,
        uniquename=false,
        uniquelist=false
        ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
A, B, and C \parencite{VomBerk2010}.
\end{document}
```

The bibliography entry is something like

```
@inproceedings{VomBerk2010,
  title = {Some Awesome Title: and do not forget the colon},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of SIGCOLON},
  series = {{COL} '07},
  author = {vom Berk, Johann and Doe, John},
  date = {2007},
}
```

This shows up as "A, B, and C (Berk 2010)", while I expected it to render as "vom Berk". If I use the `useprefix=true` I get it to render as "vom Berk", but it get indexed under 'v' and not under 'B'.

And yes, that is indeed "vom", with an m.

**EDIT** The proposed duplicate seems to address the issue with a hack, which is far less desirable than using legitimate methods.

Comment: lockstep's answer to [How can I put a name's prefix in front in citations but *not* in the bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21383/35864) *is* a legitimate method to get what you want. It is certainly far more elegant than adding a `sortname` field manually. Just because there is no package option to do what you want immediately, it does not mean that four lines of code are not a legitimate solution. (In fact I think the solution is very elegant.)

Comment: I see your point, and I stand corrected. I tried the other solution, and it does not work for me, in that I get the text citation correctly (vom Berk, 2010) but the bibliography entry as "Berk, Johann vom", although sorted under 'B'.

Comment: Use `\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother`, then. (In `\AtBeginBibliography` we now have `\toggletrue` instead of `\togglefalse`). (Your question would have been a bit easier to understand if you had stated exactly what you want at the start, I think one has to read a between the lines a bit to understand what exactly it is you want.)

Comment: I just realised that the suggestion in my comment above is essentially Audrey's comment below lockstep's answer.

Comment: Maybe [Biblatex handling of Dutch “van” prefix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226893/35864) would have been a more accurate duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `biblatex` field `sortname`, i.e.

```
@inproceedings{VomBerk2010,
title = {Some Awesome Title: and do not forget the colon},
booktitle = {Proceedings of SIGCOLON},
series = {{COL} '07},
author = {vom Berk, Johann and Doe, John},
sortname = {Berk}
date = {2007},
}
```

Comment: Ah, that works. Now I just need to remember that every time I get Zotero to re-generate the bib file.