# LNI/alpha style at BibLaTeX with the usage of multiple "von" parts

Tags: biblatex

I cite papers by "Wil van der Aalst" and I'd like to use the alphabetic style. When using the [LNI-style](https://www.gi.de/index.php?id=171), the label of the entry is `vdA01`. When using `alphabetic`, the label is `vAal01`. Is it possible to include the `d`, too? Meaning: `vdAa01` or `vdAal01`? According to `custombib`, I think, it's the "alpha" (`alph`) style, isn't it?

I got [the hint](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/350#issuecomment-152989887) that one should use `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` (Section 4.5.4) in the biblatex manual. Maybe someone has more experience than me to emulate the behavior of LNI? `custombib` also supports that

```
%file based on http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21383/9075

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend   = biber,
  style     = alphabetic,
  useprefix = true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {van der Aalst, Wil},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mhhh, as far as I can see it is hard-coded into `Biber/Internals.pm` that we take only one character from the prefix `substr(0,1)`. Maybe we would want to take all characters of the abbreviated prefix (stripped of all delimiters) instead, but I really feel that is something that needs to be changed in the innards of Biber.

Comment: I will look into adding label options for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try biblatex 3.2/biber 2.3 from the Sourceforge development folder. As @moewe noted, the substring for prefices was previously hard-coded. Biber development is often a process of making hard-coded things into options and there is very little left now that is hard coded ...

Now, there are two new options for `\field` specifications in `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` - `pstrwidth` and `pcompound` which control, respectively, how many characters to take from the prefix and whether to consider the components of a compound prefix like `van der` as separate units for the substring operations (like the `compound` option for last names). With the new options, you can get what you want with this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,pcompound=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. :star: I wonder whether this settings should be the default so that the `alphabetic` style can be used as a drop in replacement without further configuration.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable, I'll make it default.