# Bib label in alphabetic style but with full 4-digit year

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

Consider the following bibliography example using **alphabetic** style, `maxalphanames = 1` and deactivated **+** in case of multiple authors:

[image]

**How can achieve a complete 4-digit year in the label?** 
So in this case the desired output would be: **Baa1989**

I found a [**source**](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1922/biblatex-alphabetic-stil-mit-vier-statt-drei-buchstaben-biber) explaining how to define a complete custom label. But I have a hard time believing that there is no simpler more generic switch to switch. Couldn't find any in the manual.

I'm looking for a solution for **biblatex + biber**.

Thank you.

---

### MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@InProceedings{Baader1989,
  Title                    = {Direct self control of inverter-fed induction machine, a basis for speed control without speed-measurement},
  Author                   = {Baader, U. and Depenbrock, M. and Gierse, Georg},
  Booktitle                = {Industry Applications Society Annual Meeting, 1989., Conference Record of the 1989 IEEE},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Pages                    = {486-492 vol.1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
            backend=biber,
            maxnames=99,
            maxalphanames=1,    
            backref=true,
            doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
            backref=false,
            ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\bibliography{references.bib} 

\begin{document}
Citation: \cite{Baader1989}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just go with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,pcompound=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}    
  }
}` (line breaks not to scale).

Comment: I really thought there would be a duplicate on this site, but I couldn't find one, so I went ahead and answered. We have the similar [Biblatex alphabetic style like Smith, 2005](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68862/35864), but there something else is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see you will have to resort to `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`, but that is not too bad.

We can just copy the default from `biblatex.def` and change `\field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}` to `\field{year}`

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,pcompound=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}    
  }
}
```

and that's it.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{Baader1989,
  Title                    = {Direct self control of inverter-fed induction machine, a basis for speed control without speed-measurement},
  Author                   = {Baader, U. and Depenbrock, M. and Gierse, Georg},
  Booktitle                = {Industry Applications Society Annual Meeting, 1989., Conference Record of the 1989 IEEE},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Pages                    = {486-492 vol.1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,%
            backend=biber,
            maxnames=99,
            maxalphanames=1,    
            backref=true,
            doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
            backref=false,
            ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1,pcompound=true]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,pcompound=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}    
  }
}

\begin{document}
Citation: \cite{Baader1989}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `pcompound = true` do? It is undefined und throws and error. Leaving that out everyhting seems to work.

Comment: @thewaywewalk `pcompound` is a new option that was introduced in `biblatex 3.2`. It is the `compound` equivalent for name prefixes. It was implemented because of [LNI/alpha style at BibLaTeX with the usage of multiple “von” parts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276168/35864). Either make an update of `biblatex` and Biber, or just drop the `pcompound=true`.